# Should I use GlusterFS for mail server?

Tags: email-server, nfs, glusterfs, fuse

I'm planing to use GlusterFS for my mail server. But I read that GlusterFS have problems with small file ( and mail are small files). What's the problems with GlusterFS when come to working with small file?

I also know that GlusterFS have 2 mount options, FUSE and NFS.

Now I wondering what option should I use and how to avoid the problems

Comment: do you plan to habe a such big space requirement that a normal filesystem would not work?

Comment: Hmmm no not that big, I have a lab about: Find and evaluate about using glusterFS with mailserver, and problems with writing small file.

Comment: i aint well known to this fs, but in my point of View, tske some old pcs eith hdds, gluster 'em and try it out, monitor the network and disk, try some fsil over and you see what you get? ;)